# Product Gallery Image Name match show something

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to check gallery images in Magento 1.9.2.4 store to see if they contain thumb.jpg in the image name. I have inserted the following block in the more views area in media.phtml file:

```
  <?php foreach ($galleryImages as $_image): ?>
  <?php $thumb = $helpImg->getImg($_product); ?>
  <?php// echo $thumb; ?>    
  <?php $mystring = $thumb;?>
  <?php $findme   = 'thumb.jpg';?>
   <?php $pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);?>
   <?php if($pos !== false);?>
   <!-- there is a thumb-->
<?php else:?> 
  <!-- there is no thumb-->
<?php endif; ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

When I uncomment the echo $thumb, I can see the image url outputting on screen, so I know it's not empty. 
I am not seeing any errors in logs, so kind of stumped why it's not working. 
All I see on product view page is a partial page that stopped when it hit the media.phtml file.

Thanks

Comment: I think you have unneccessary `<?php foreach ($galleryImages as $_image): ?>` loop here. You can put your code outside of more views, since a product can have only one thumb image.

Comment: What I am trying to do is use this logic so that if a product image in gallery has the name thumb.jpg in it, it does not show in the product gallery. That's why I have it inside the foreach loop.